# Allegation and mixture typical problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio, mixing

I have tried this question by ratio method and I am getting my answer as 35.29% but they say this is wrong. Please help

A solution of hydrochloric acid and sulphuric acid has 40% of hydrochloric acid . A solution of hydrochloric acid and nitric acid has a composition ratio of 2:7. These two solutions are mixed in a way that the new solution formed has more sulphuric acid than nitric acid and hydrochloric acid constitutes x% of this solution. What can be the minimum value of x?

Thanks

Comment: This question would probably feel more at home at [chemistry.stackexchange.com](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: this is not a chemistry type question.

Comment: Then convert it to a question not including chemistry.

Comment: either provide solution or don't waste your time here gentleman

Comment: I'm trying to help here. First of all, don't expect people to solve your homework. Second of all, since this is *math* stackexchange, a lot of people that could potentially help you are scared away by the chemistry part of your question. Third, rewriting the question in a purely mathematical way may help you see the solution yourself, because you're not being distracted by the irrelevant aspects of your phrasing. You're welcome.

Comment: first of all I am not expecting anyone to solve this. I am just asking for hint or something. second a pure mathemetician will find relevant what he need to solve this because this question is related to allegation and mixture topic. terms used in this question are related to chemistry but that does not change the nature of question. third if i will not get an answer i am definitely going to rewrite this question and you dont need to tell me that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take a volume A of the first mixture, and a volume $B$ of the second mixture. Then in the final mixture there will be 3/5A of sulphuric acid, 7/9B of nitric acid and 2/5A+2/9B of hydrochloric acid. Hence, the final proportion of hydrochloric acid is (2/5A+2/9B)/(A+B). We also know that there can be no more nitric acid than sulphuric acid in the final mixture, thus 7/9B<3/5A .

You can now check that the minimum is obtained when the nitric acid is just less than the sulphuric acid, or when 7/9B=3/5A. Working the math out, you should get that the minimum proportion of hydrochloric acid is 20/62=0.3225806.